# ADB and root access on Android 7.0

Tags: android, adb, rom

I tweak MTK devices, I just like to tweak the build.prop, wallpapers and boot animations etc and remove/add system apps.

I find the best way has always been to get the OS, use Android Image Kitchen to change the ro.secure, ro.adb.secure and ro.debuggable settings in the default.prop file. re-build the boot.img and reflash that.

Of course you have to make sure you unlock the bootloader first.

I don;t really want root access, getting ADB root is all I need to play and have some fun!!

So, I have a device that I have done this on and I simply cannot get ADB root access.

adb shell getprop commands show all the above default.prop settings have worked and are correct.

adb root doesn't error

adb remount rw gives me the classic error "Not running as root. Try adb root first"

I am also periodically getting the "adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (40); killing..." however I  just enter adb devices a few times and it all connects after a few attempts.

I have managed this method for other Android 7.1, 7.0 devices with no issues, but i did have an engineer/debug boot.img.

Any ideas on how to get root would be much appreciated? It is very frustarting that this has just stopped working.

Comment: It would surely be easier for the community to help with this if you could edit the question to identify the device you're having problems with.

Comment: SO, Sorry, Of course. It's a Poptel P9000 device. A Rugged device based on Helio P23 6750 chipset

Comment: Please edit the actual question to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for the down votes, really useful.

So I answered this myself with a little help over at XDA forums. I needed to remove the verify tag from the fstab file in boot. After doing this the device then gave me ADB root.

Comment: jealous of your question man, they don't understand what your talking about.. it's like you didn't already give enough information .. Moderator Harry Potters, Expeliumus

Comment: Haha, Cheers for that. Its also bad that the site markets to my developers constantly about getting a new job too!!